# msmq unsupported format name operation although the format names are correct

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

I am debugging though a wcf service. I have a service attached and debugging along with the exe. During the process, I get unsupported format name operation error when initializing queues with strings. However, I am pretty sure and double checked that the strings are of correct syntax, and I have all the permission and access to the queues.

```
RequestQueue = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(correctString);
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different formats that can be specified in the MessageQueue constructor, that use differing syntax, depending on if they are public/ private queues, dead-letter-queues, journal queues, and so on.

For example:

**Public queue:** `MachineName\QueueName`

**Private queue:** `MachineName\Private$\QueueName`

*Can you post an example of what you are using?*

Also, if you are using an [Format Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.formatname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), check the spelling of your format string:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:YOURMACHINENAME\private$\YourQueueName
```

Please note that the first part FormatName:DIRECT is **case-sensitive**. (More in-depth documentation about the syntax can be found in the MSDN here: [Direct Format Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Here is an example of a request queue: <add key="OneTypeOfRequestQueue" value="FormatName:DIRECT=OS:AppServerDev\private$\one_type_of_request"/>